# I don't know why this code isn't work

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search, knapsack-problem, branch-and-bound

The breadth first search with branch-and-bound pruning code for the 0-1 knapsack problem
I typed code almost same way as pesudo code.
But it occurs error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at knapsack_breadth.Ex1.knapsack2(Ex1.java:67)
    at knapsack_breadth.Ex1.main(Ex1.java:136)
```

As i think,the cause is on the v.level
 
so when I call some value from an array with a index that is v.level 
it bring me error about index out
 
after

```
u.level = v.level + 1;
value of v.level change to v.level + 1

ex) print(v.level); ---> 1
 u.level = v.level + 1;
 print(v.level); --->2
```

---

```
public class Ex1 {

    public static int maxprofit;

    public class node {
        int level;
        int profit;
        int weight;
        //Constructor of Node

    }
    public class Queue1 {
        ArrayList<node> list = new ArrayList();
        int size;
        node deq;
        void enqueue(node e){
            list.add(e);
        }
        node dequeue(){
            size = list.size();
            if(size==0){
                return null;
            }
            else{
                deq = list.get(size-1);
                list.remove(size-1);
                return deq;
            }
        }
        boolean isEmpty(){
            size = list.size();
            if(size==0){
                return true;
            }
            else{return false;}

        }
    }
    void knapsack2(int n,int p[],int w[],int weight){
        Queue1 Q = new Queue1();
        node u = new node(); 
        node v = new node();
        int count=0;
        int store_v_level;
        int store_v_weight;
        int store_v_profit;
        maxprofit = 0;
        /*while(!is_empty(Q)){
            Q.poll();

        }*/ //Initialize Q to be empty
        v.level=0; v.profit =0; v.weight=0; //Initialize v to be the root
        Q.enqueue(v);

        while (!Q.isEmpty()){ //while Q is not empty
            v = Q.dequeue();

            u.level = v.level + 1;
            u.weight = v.weight + w[u.level-1];
            u.profit = v.profit + p[u.level-1];

            if(u.weight <= weight && u.profit > maxprofit){
                maxprofit = u.profit;

            }
            if(bound(u,n,p,w,weight) > maxprofit){
                Q.enqueue(u);

            }
            u.weight = v.weight;
            u.profit = v.profit;
            if (bound(u,n,p,w,weight) > maxprofit){
                Q.enqueue(u);
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("maxprofit : " + maxprofit);

    }
    void node_test(){
        Queue<node> Q = new LinkedList<node>();
        node u = new node();
        u.level = 1; u.weight = 1; u.profit = 1;
        node v = new node();
        v.level = 2; v.weight = 2; v.profit = 2;

    }

    float bound(node u,int n,int p[], int w[], int weight){
        int j, k; // index
        int totweight;
        float result;

        if(u.weight >= weight)
            return 0;
        else{
            result = u.profit;
            j = u.level + 1;
            totweight = u.weight;
            while ( j<=n && totweight + w[j-1] <= weight){

                totweight += w[j-1];
                result += p[j-1];
                j++;

            }
            k=j;
            if(k<=n){
                result += (weight-totweight)*(p[k-1]/w[k-1]);
            }

            return result;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Ex1 knapsack = new Ex1();
        int p[] = {40,30,50,10};
        int w[] = {2,5,10,5};
        int weight = 16;
        int n = 4;
        System.out.println("start");
        knapsack.knapsack2(n, p, w, weight);
    }
}
```

Comment: just google for this part : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
it means you are trying to access to 5th element of an array which has 4 or less elements

Comment: Why would you use a List to represent a queue? Use ArrayDeque instead! Btw did you tried to debug the code?

Comment: @Stultuske  I already know that I am trying to access to 5th element of an array which array has 4... My question is not about that. I wonder why v.level chage to (v.level+1). it brings me  the error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 .

Comment: @SMA I have tried to debug for many hours..but i cannot solve. .

Comment: what makes you think it does? anyway, you iterate while there are still elements in your que. if there are more elements in there than in your array(s), you'll end up with that